# Data Structure of a Serialized ArrayList<object> Binary File

Tags: java, android, serialization, arraylist

In my Android app, I create a Serialized ArrayList and write it as a binary file using writeObject(). I want to take that file, copy it to a PC and read it into a program (that I would need to write in C++), where I would view / edit the information, write it back out to the file, and send it back to the Android device, where it would interpreted correctly.

I have examined the binary file with a hex editor; it contains the field names and the data, along with other binary information that I cannot interpret.

Is there a structure definition that exists of the serialized object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/2915) describes the binary format of `Serializable` objects in some detail.

The [Java Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html) describes the format in excruciating detail.